# Master - Detail example

Tags: symfony

Does anyone have a Master/Detail symfony2 example? I was trying to add multiple products to a category, all from one form, but I´m not abble to get parent id in the controller to persist data.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the entity and form you have so far?

Comment: What I want is to create a Category and 10 or 15 products (name, price) y one form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look there: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.html#the-controller

I think that is what you need.

Comment: The site seems to be down, source also available on Github: https://github.com/dsyph3r/symblog-docs/blob/master/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.rst